# VB.net Project using MySQL user locally

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Need Help.

I made a vb.net project, it is already finished. but my problem is, after i install the project i made to another computer. it can't connect to the database unless the WAMP server is open. is there a way to user without opening WAMP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMP stands for Windows Apache **MySQL** PHP. It runs MySQL server, so you need it to access database. Option is that user on another computer runs some MySQL server or connects to web server that runs database required for application.

You could also consider using Microsoft Access database. In this case you don't need server. All database is just in one MS Access file.

Comment: is there no other possible solution? I have only have 2 days left to pass this project.

Comment: Maybe you could check out http://www.sqlite.org/, but i am not familiar with it... But even with using MS Access database you can encounter problem if there is no MS Access installed on user's computer. The best way is either install some database server locally or connect to web server.

Comment: Ok. can you suggest an easy solution to my problem? And I really need to use SQL not access. Thanks man.

Comment: How about SQLite? I've found quite good tutorial: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitevb/
It doesn't need server to run since it becomes part of your application. So this should do the trick.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that one. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.